# MySQl trigger error on insert and update same table (Error Code: 1064)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1064, database-trigger

```
TRIGGER `dn_name`.`schedule_arrive` AFTER INSERT
    ON `dn_name`.`administration_schedule`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    DECLARE approx_hr INT(11), update_hr DATETIME;
    SELECT approx_hr FROM `administration_routes` WHERE id = NEW.route_id INTO approx_hr;
    SELECT DATE_ADD(new.depart_time, INTERVAL approx_hr HOUR_MINUTE) INTO update_hr;    
    UPDATE administration_schedule SET arrive_time=approx_hr WHERE id = NEW.id;

END$$
```

On running insert query, I designed to select approx hour from **route** table with related id and set that value to `approx_hr`, `increase datetime` from new inserted depart time and assign to `update_hr` and finally update the `arrive_time` field in trigger enabled same table. But on executing my query, the system show as follows;

> **Error Code:** 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', update_hr datetime;
>   select approx_hr from `administration_routes` where id =' at line 7

Comment: You are not allowed to action the table which fired the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

About the `NEW.myColumn` and `OLD.myColumn`, you can only use them when using "BEFORE" something. After an insert, you don't have an `OLD.myColumn` or `NEW.myColumn` gut a current one. for what you want to do, use "BEFORE INSERT" and change your "SELECT,... SELECT..., UPDATE..." to a simple

```
SET NEW.arrive_time = DATE_ADD(NEW.depart_time,INTERVAL ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `before update` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `dn_name`.`schedule_arrive` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `dn_name`.`administration_schedule`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE approx_hr INT(11), update_hr DATETIME;

    SELECT approx_hr FROM `administration_routes` WHERE id = NEW.route_id INTO approx_hr;

    SELECT DATE_ADD(new.depart_time, INTERVAL approx_hr HOUR_MINUTE) INTO update_hr; 

    SET NEW.arrive_time = approx_hr;

END$$
```